# Rails ActiveAdmin custom filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ransack

I have 3 models : User, Report and Invoices.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reports , :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :invoices, :through => :reports

 class Report < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoices, allow_destroy: true

 class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :report, optional: false
  validate :invoice_period
```

I have started using ActiveAdmin and on the Invoice page I would like to be able to filter based on a given user name(User has many invoices through reports)
I have looked through documentation but I'm not having a solution or start on how to do this. So the question would be how to implement this filter?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer will be irrelevant because I did't work with active admin but I will give a shot.

1. Shoudn't `Report` contain `belongs_to :user`?
2. Pass some params to the action of controller that shows `Invoice page` and show invoices based on `User`.

   ```
   @invoices = User.where(:name => params[:user_name]).invoices if params[:user_name].present ?
   ```

and if you have other params you can use scopes to join query. This article will help https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/

probably in your `show invoice controller` you have query based on `Invoice` so you will have to use more adv. sql (`join` etc.) to find users through reports.